# Angular/Laravel - outputting json data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

i am fetching data, that i want to output from mysql with laravel query builder and converting it to JSON format, as w3Schools suggested
[W3schools SQL link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp)
And afterwards printing fetched mysql data with AngularJS help, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all and it shows me a blank page.

**Laravel route**

```
Route::get('/' ,  [
    'as' => 'homepage',
    'uses' => 'indexController@main'
]);
```

**IndexController**

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function main(){
      $data =  json_encode(array('user_posts' =>\DB::table('posts')
                ->orderBy('added_on', 'desc')
                ->get()));

    return view('index', ['posts' => $data]);
    }

}
```

**index.php view with AngularJS controller**

```
<head>

            <!--Angulare -->
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
            <!--Applicazione -->
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="js/controller/PoolController.js"></script>
            <script src="js/service/poolService.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
          <td>{{ x.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ x.age }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      </div>





   ### Angular Module and controller ###
      <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
          $http.get("/")
          .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.user_posts;
          });
      });
      </script>
    </body>
```

**Json output how it looks like:**

```
{"user_posts":[{"id":1,"username":"Moly","age":22,"added_on":"2017-01-05 08:51:18"},
{"id":2,"username":"katja","age":22,"added_on":"2017-01-05 08:51:18"},
{"id":3,"username":"rumanova","age":22,"added_on":"2017-01-05 08:51:18"}]}
```

**I've tried so far in AngularJS controller:**

changing:

```
 $http.get("/")
```

With

```
 $http.get("homepage")
```

Also tried changing

```
response.data.user_posts
```

with

```
response.data.posts
```

Basically i'm kinda lost and can't seem to understand, what i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are always returning a rendered view which will never be a valid JSON response. Instead, check if it's an ajax request. Also, Laravel provides `collection()`'s which should be used in favor of raw arrays or json encoding where possible to provide stack cohesion. Try this:

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    return response()->json(collect(['user_posts' =>\DB::table('posts')
        ->orderBy('added_on', 'desc')
    ]));
}

return view('index);
```

Also, make sure you're injecting the `$request` into your controller's method:

```
public function main(Request $request) {
```

Furthermore, `Angular` doesn't have any idea about Laravel's routes, but that's okay. If you're using scripts directly inside of the view file, you still have access to Laravel's helpers, you can make your endpoint request:

```
$http.get('{{route('homepage')}}')
```

Otherwise, if your Angular is in a script, just do:

```
$http.get('/');
```

And you will access it within your HTTP request callback with `response.user_posts`.

Comment: when i check if ajax request exist then it says false, and just returns the view, but how exactly can i output data that i got from query then? I'm now quite confused how does laravel with Angular works to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

You can use $routeProvider instead of $html like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/homepage', {
        templateUrl: '/homepage.html',
        controller: 'customersCtrl'
      });

}]);
```